# Permission error for certain folders while executing a perl file in Linux server

Tags: linux, perl

I am executing a perl file in Linux server for automation scripts. It would be of great help if you could help on this.

My current server is a two node cluster server and I am using perl automation scripts. I dont want to copy my perl file to both the nodes so I want to execute the command remotely using "ssh" command to the second node. My node 1 server is abd01 and my node 2 server is abd02. I have logged into abd01 and running a remote command for abd02. Below is my command :

```
ssh -q abd02 "ls -lh \$(find \-L \/opt\/emageon\/backup\/\${UNIQUE_CUSTOMER}*/\$(date '+%Y%m%d') -type f)|grep sfdisk___sr0 | awk 'END {print NR}'"
```

I get an output value of "8" for this.

I am using the same command in a perl file along with the escape characters and when I run the perl file with the command "perl icount.pl" I do not get the desired output. Below is the perl script of icount.pl file that i am using

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Config;
use Socket;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use IO::Socket::INET;


my $icount;
$icount = `ssh -q root\@rcs02 \"ls -lh \$(find -L /opt/emageon/backup/\${UNIQUE_CUSTOMER}*/\$(date \'+%Y%m%d\') -type f)|grep sfdisk___sr0 | awk 'END {print NR}'"`;

print "Value is $icount /n";
```

The output that I get for this is as mentioned below;

```
Value is -rw-r----- 1 druser druser 3.1M Mar  4 01:59 /opt/emageon/backup/0050569143c5/20160304/drbackup/info/drosbackup.sh.log
0
```

For most of the files I am getting messages as shown below

bash: line 126: /opt/emageon/backup/005056916d4d/20160304/scbackup/DARC/201603040416/controlfile.txt: Permission denied

I am really not sure why I am not getting the output of 8 when I am running the same command in perl file. Please help me on this as I am stuck amidst my automation scripts

Comment: It's probably related to quoting and escaping of meta-characters

Comment: I have tried all the combinations of escaping and I am still not getting the desired output. :(

Comment: What is `$UNIQUE_CUSTOMER`? Is that an environment variable and can you reasonably expect it to be set on the remote host as you run `ssh`?

Comment: yes $UNIQUE_CUSTOMER is an environment variable and the same is set on the remote host as well.

Comment: Try using [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) and letting it [do the quoting](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#Shell-quoting).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `qx{}` instead of the backtick operator. 
In particular you can use `qx' ...'`.
Using single-quote as a delimiter protects the command from Perl's double-quote interpolcation, passing it on to the shell instead.

You can omit the single quotes for the date format, they are not required.

And you can replace the awk script with `wc -l`.

Also you are using `ls` together with `find`. Usually "find" by itself is enough. Checkout the -printf option in the `find` man page. It can print the user name of the owner and much more. You can also use find to restrict the result to things owned by a particular user.

Comment: I used the below command;
   
"$icount = qx {ssh -q rcs02 \"ls -lh \$(find -L /opt/emageon/backup/\${UNIQUE_CUSTOMER}*/\$(date \+%Y%m%d\) -type f)|grep sfdisk___sr0 | wc -l END {print NR}"};"
I got the same output as explained in the original question.

Comment: replace qx{..} with qx'...'